# P2P Connection between two Windows Phones 7

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, bluetooth, p2p, wifi

Is it possible to create an peer to peer connection(bluetooth or wlan) between two windows phones which aren't in the same wlan network?

I only found solutions which are possible, when both phones are in the same network

Answer (score 2):

The phones will both be on private networks behind a firewalls so you will need to send the data through a server/pc. If you wrote your own p2p network, or wrote the code/used a library to use an existing network you would be able to create the appearance that the phones are connected to each other directly.

Comment: What firewall? He's talking about a direct Bluetooth connection or an ad-hoc Wi-Fi connection. There's no firewall unless Windows Phone 7 has one.

Comment: Two separate wireless networks, ie one phone in one location on Wi-Fi, another phone at a different location on a different network.  RE: (which aren't in the same wlan network), P2P on the same network is relatively easy on mango but that to my isn't the question..

Comment: Sounds to me, seeing as he mentioned Bluetooth, that he's talking about P2P within a PAN, not cross-WAN P2P. @Philipp?

Comment: i think it's about direct wireless connection with no other devices except two win7 phones.

Comment: Ok - I have two different window phones which only have my client software in common. The probably haven't a connection to their carrier and aren't in a w-lan network and I just want a way, that this two phones can send short messages to each other.
Bluetooth or W-Lan isn't important

Answer (score 1):

Windows phone and thus silverlight doesn't support "listen" command for sockets. they can only act as an client so you can't create peer to peer application in this platform.